# Not all .mid MIDI files working

Tags: 11.04, totem, midi

I have several MIDI files on my computer. They ALL play fine on 10.10 or earlier, but in 11.04 Natty maybe only about 50% of them play. Totem will recognize all the files in Natty and even show track time and show the song playing, but no audio. Anyone care to venture why some MIDI files work and some dont in Natty? The same files work fine on 10.10 and a 10.04 system.

Comment: Did you have some extra instruments installed?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with MIDI files, do they need proprietary codecs? And did you do a fresh install or upgrade?

Comment: Do you use Timidity++ ?

Comment: No I do not use Timidity. MIDI files to the best of my knowledge dont need anything special to play. Up until now, Ive always just double clicked them and they play fine in Totem. Also, Ive never had any extra instruments installed. My versions of Natty are fresh vanilla installs.

Comment: Thanks for any tips and troubleshooting advice. I may end going back to 10.10 which worked fine.

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu-restricted-extras? If not, your files will probably not work. Also, try installing some more sound fonts. (BTW, I don't have any problems on 11.04 with Midi files, so I'm going to suggest to you that reverting to 10.10 is just an extreme "solution", and not really the solution at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem.

The best workaround I have found (to save downgrading) is to just install Timidity++ and then associate one of the interfaces (I use the GTK+ one) with MIDI files.
It is not the best solution for instance if you have any midi files in your Totem playlists you will still get silence, and also means that you have to have two music players, but it lets me play all my MIDI files.

I'll post back if I find a better solution.

Comment: AAAhhhhh. Thanks for the tip! Im working on a big project right now :( and time is important so I downgraded to 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to play .midis as in listening to monophonic sounds? Surely a better idea than opening them rawly is to load them in a Digital Audio Workstation (DAWs, also known as sequencers). That way you can play the melodies in a proper synthesizer, a sampled piano, etc.

Comment: Hi vemv. For 5 years I have been accustomed to opening them quickly in totem just to listen to the music. If I want something more like a sample I will use LMMS or whatever. Just using totem for quick referencing.